# How to rename multiple files in this case .jpg?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, file-rename

I'm trying to change the file names of a few ".jpg" to a custom name followed by a number. So it would look something like this: **Name1.jpg; Name2.jpg; Name3.jpg**

Problem that it doesn't change the current name to the new name. the dir is correct.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuAnI.jpg

Source of the tutorial: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rename-multiple-files-using-python/

I'm using Python3 on Windows 10 64 Bit

I tried the `dir` in four different ways.

```
1. os.listdir('C:/Users/Inty/Desktop/test'):
2. os.listdir('C://Users//Inty//Desktop//test'):
3. os.listdir('C:\Users\Inty\Desktop\\test'):
4. os.listdir('C:\\Users\\Inty\\Desktop\\test'):
5. os.listdir('C:/Users/Inty/Desktop/test/'):
```

Also played with the `dst = '.jpg' to '.JPG'` but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

```
# Imports
import os


# Functions
def main():
    i = 0

    for filename in os.listdir('C:/Users/Inty/Desktop/test'):
        dst = 'Name' + str(i) + '.JPG'
        src = 'C:/Users/Inty/Desktop/test' + filename
        dst = 'C:/Users/Inty/Desktop/test' + dst

        os.rename(src, dst)
        i += 1

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Maybe read [How to debug small programs.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) But also, in the words of Brian Kernighan, [*"The most effective debugging tool is still careful thought, coupled with judiciously placed print statements."*](https://en.m.wikiquote.org/wiki/Brian_Kernighan)

Comment: Hello tripleee,
Process finished with exit code 0
I checked with two other computers one including a mac. Same result.

Comment: Maybe that article was overwhelming. What I'm saying is that you can solve this yourself by making your code print or log the precise values of your variables and reveal to you where the bug is.

Comment: Here's $20 that says your Mac does not have a path named `c:/Users/Inty/Desktop/test`

Comment: I modified the code a bit. The main reason was because I had ```if __name__ == '__main__':``` Inside the ```for``` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

I modified the code a bit. The main reason was because I had `if __name__ == '__main__':` Inside the `for` loop.

That made the `if` inside the function.

```
import os

# Functions

PATH = 'C:\\Users\\Inty\\Desktop\\test'


def main():
    i = 0

    for filename in os.listdir(PATH):
        dst = 'Name' + str(i) + '.JPG'
        src = os.path.join(PATH, filename)
        dst = os.path.join(PATH, dst)

        os.rename(src, dst)
        i += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a slash.  Perhaps you want:

```
src = 'C:/Users/Inty/Desktop/test/' + filename
dst = 'C:/Users/Inty/Desktop/test/' + dst
```

A nicer approach is to use `os.path.join`:

```
src = os.path.join('C:/Users/Inty/Desktop/test', filename)
```

Comment: Hello Lak, Thank you for the quick response. I´ve tried doing the os.path.join but unfortunately it still doesn't seem to do the trick.